# Largura errada na div do chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

Estou tentando fazer um efeito de, quando escolho uma opção no select, mostro a div correspodente com `highchart`.
Tem 2 problemas:

1- A largura do chart não está completando corretamente a largura da div.

2- Não estou conseguindo pensar em um jeito de esconder as outras opções quando uma for mostrada. (serão mais de 3 opções, no exemplo tem duas para não complicar muito).

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6S9cZ/)**

HTML

```
<div style="width:80%;">
<select class="selectchart" id="selectsolicitacoes"><option>Por mês</option><option value="#hg3">Por semana</option><option value="#hg2">Por dia</option></select><br>
<div id="hg2" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; display: none;">        </div>
<div id="hg3" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; display: none;">     </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#selectsolicitacoes').change(function(){
    var element = $(this).val();
    $(element).show();
});
});
```

Comment: Igor, é isto que procura? http://jsfiddle.net/6S9cZ/1/

Comment: Olá.Obrigado. Resolveu o segundo problema, o primeiro ainda não. O chart não está aparecendo ocupando toda a `div` só metade dela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui fica uma sugestão:

### Mostrar e esconder opções:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $graficos = $('[id^=hg]').hide();
    $('#selectsolicitacoes').change(function(){
        var element = this.value; // tirei o "$(this).val()", não precisa de jQuery aqui
        $graficos.hide(); // esconder todos os elementos que cujo ID começa por "hg"
        $(element).show();
    });
});
```

Eu sugiro dar um ID mais longo para não correr o risco de o meu código "apanhar" outros elementos no mesmo seletor. Talvez seja mesmo boa ideia usar uma div à volta desses gráficos para ter um seletor mais "certeiro", tipo `$('#novaDiv [id^=hg]').hide();`

### Largura do Highchart

O problema parece ser o Highcharts não conseguir saber a largura de um elemento que está escondido. Isto é um bug [conhecido](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/issues/3) do Highcharts.

Assim, se no CSS inicial os elementos não estiverem com `display: none;`mas sim com `opacity: 0;` o Highcharts consegue renderizar com a largura correta. A partir daí pode usar o código como eu tinha colocado.

Juntando a esta ideia o uso do evento onLoad do Hicharts, pode usar assim:

```
$('#hg2').highcharts({
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function (event) {
                $('#hg2').hide().css('opacity', 1);
            }
        }
    },
// fazer isto em cada gráfico
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/6S9cZ/8/)

Esta solução é baseada [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8403723/2256325), as maneiras que conhecia de antes, que são remendos para o "bug" são atribuir `width: 100%;` à div do Hicharts, ou chamar um `$(window).resize();`

Comment: Sergio, eu já havia tentado o `width: 100%` mas se você reparar, o elemento superior tem `width:80%` e quando colocamos 100% o chart ultrapassa o elemento acima.

Comment: @IgorMartins como disse é um bug conhecido do Highcharts, vou dar uma olhada pela web de novo. A outra solucão que referí é esta: http://jsfiddle.net/6S9cZ/4/

Comment: @IgorMartins, completei a resposta com informação "fresca".

Comment: show!!! muito obrigado pela paciência.